# Can anyone suggest a program I can use to make a simple animation?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, animation, animate

Apologies if this question has been asked before. But can anyone suggest a program I can use to make a simple animation?

I’m trying to make an animation similar to the following:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4cLzRHpjodU

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r40dZLjBBNQ

My animation will be simple and short. Around 1 minute using just text and vector based images (I.e. no photographs). I haven’t played with animation for a while, so I don’t really know where to start.

I was thinking of using either Adobe Animate or After Effects. (Animate looks more suitable though.)

Or I could make the images in Illustrator then upload into Animate? Apparently Photoshop CC also does animation?

I’ve never used Adobe Animate before, but I have plenty of experience with Adobe products+design, so I’m hoping to pick it up as I go.

Any suggestions?

The start is always the hardest!

Many thanks as always.

Tim

Comment: Just so you know, you don't need to add the same comment on every answer, you could just add it under the question. Good to see that you found a solution!

Comment: You mean click "Answer your question" and add the comment there?? I went to do that, but there was a popup message implying not to use that button.

Comment: no I meant add as a comment like you just did :) People would read the question and the comment below it.

Comment: So where do I add the comment? Below my question or below the preferred answer?

Comment: Whichever you prefer, it's not really that important. I personally would add under the question if i'd be the one asking, it's more visible (I think). Or as an [edit] at the bottom of the question itself, some people do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These animations might *look* simple because it's just solid color objects and text, but some of the movements and the transitions would take more work with the wrong tool.

You're definitely on the right track with either Animate or After Effects, it depends what's the final format you're going to export to and how much experience you have on either software.

Personally I'd use After Effects since you have plenty of built-in effects and extra plugins. It's also easier to produce motion blur, 3D effects and the text transitions.

I'd also recommend *against* Photoshop animations in this case; the timeline is really cumbersome to work with, keyframes are not as powerful as in AE, I use it only for the simplest animations of a few frames or a few seconds.

Comment: The second one is allmost dfinitely easier in AE.

Comment: @joojaa that's exactly what I thought when I saw all those characters jumping around like that

Comment: Hey guys,

I ended up going with After Effects. Pretty daunting at first, but not that bad once you know the layout etc. I spent a day learning the basics and then a day making the animation. 

The manager is happy with the end product, so thanks sooo much for the help. I would have gone with Animate, so your suggestions pointed me in the right direction.

I found a plugin which others may appreciate: 
https://misterhorse.tv/animation-composer

Made my job 10x easier.

Answer (score 1):

While most of these videos are probably made in After Effects, it is possible to use Animate. Photoshop does animation, but with multiple layers it does get kind of complex and I'd avoid it.

The animated illustrations are either done in Illustrator (Vector) or Photoshop and imported into AfterEffects/Animate or done directly in the program (mostly for simple shapes or depending on your skill level).

I'd recommend importing into AfterEffects and animating there. The keyword is "motion design".

Comment: Hey guys,

I ended up going with After Effects. Pretty daunting at first, but not that bad once you know the layout etc. I spent a day learning the basics and then a day making the animation. 

The manager is happy with the end product, so thanks sooo much for the help. I would have gone with Animate, so your suggestions pointed me in the right direction.

I found a plugin which others may appreciate: 
https://misterhorse.tv/animation-composer

Made my job 10x easier.

Answer (score 1):

My five cents: Animate is used a lot for TV animation because there're adequate painting tools in it and it's simple to use. But for the examples you provided, motion design as Benedikt mentioned, it's going to be hell.

After Effects is the tool of your choice and there're tons of tutorials on it.

Photoshop is a strict no-no: tools are too limited.

Comment: Hey guys,

I ended up going with After Effects. Pretty daunting at first, but not that bad once you know the layout etc. I spent a day learning the basics and then a day making the animation. 

The manager is happy with the end product, so thanks sooo much for the help. I would have gone with Animate, so your suggestions pointed me in the right direction.

I found a plugin which others may appreciate: 
https://misterhorse.tv/animation-composer

Made my job 10x easier.